# Generate master-detail HTML tables (stacked and embedded) with PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, html-table

I am trying to accomplish something like this: http://mediaformations.com/accordion-tables-with-jquery/ but my HTML tables will be dynamically populated.

I have two tables:

```
+------------------------+
|    TB_ACTIVE_USERS     |
+------------------------+
|  ID  |  NAME  | EMAIL  |
+------------------------+

+---------------------------+
|        TB_POSTS           |
+---------------------------+
|USER_ID|PDATE|SUBJECT|BODY |
+---------------------------+
```

and this is what I would like to get in the form of stacked and embedded HTML tables:

```
+------------------------+
|  LIST OF ACTIVE USERS  |
+------------------------+
|      USER 1 NAME       |
+------------------------+
|+----------------------+|
||DATE | SUBJECT | BODY ||
|+----------------------+|
||10/01| Lorem1  |IpsumA||
|+----------------------+|
||10/01| Lorem1B |IpsumB||
|+----------------------+|
||10/02| Lorem1C |IpsumC||
|+----------------------+|
+------------------------+
|      USER 2 NAME       |
+------------------------+
|+----------------------+|
||DATE | SUBJECT | BODY ||
|+----------------------+|
||10/01| Lorem2  |IpsumA||
|+----------------------+|
+------------------------+
|      USER 3 NAME       |
+------------------------+
|+----------------------+|
||DATE | SUBJECT | BODY ||
|+----------------------+|
||10/02| Lorem3  |IpsumA||
|+----------------------+|
||10/02| Lorem3B |IpsumB||
|+----------------------+|
+------------------------+
```

Using this query:

```
SELECT usr.name, pdate, subject, body 
FROM tb_posts
JOIN tb_active_users AS usr
ON user_id = usr.id
WHERE pdate >=  CURDATE()
ORDER BY usr.name, pdate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

join the tables on ID = USER_ID, group by ID and order by ID, DATE

perhaps "select * from ACTIVE_USERS, POSTS where ID = USER_ID group by ID order by DATE ASC"

Comment: Thanks, GROUP BY will return just one row per user.

Comment: My main interest is in getting the query results parsed in a way that may allow me to show the results as an HTML table like "List of Active Users" above.

Comment: select * from ACTIVE_USERS, POSTS where ID = USER_ID order by ID, DATE ASC  then cycle through the results so when id changes you know to write the new name row with a td where colspan=3 , then the row with the column names in th elements followed by a row with the  data etc, checking each new row to see if the ID has changed yet...